# Is it acceptable to execute functions with undefined variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a ajax form that populates select lists with values based on the previous selected select list item.  This form is used in 3 different views with each view adding an extra select list.  I have written some basic validation code that keeps the form process in sync and doesn't confuse the user.

I have written one function that handles all 3 forms in an external script file.

**My Question:**
Is it acceptable or is there anything I need to worry about if some of my variables are undefined based on the form and view?

**Here is some sample code that illustrates my question:**
Note: These are not the actual names of my variables.

```
    (function ($){
    var objects = {sl1:$('#SelectList1'),sl2:$('#SelectList2'),sl3:$('#SelectList3'),lbl1:$('#Label1'),lbl2:$('#Label2'),lbl3:$('#Label3')};
    objects.sl1.change(function(){
    mapValues();
    }
    function mapValues(){
    objects.lbl1.text(objects.sl1.val());
    objects.lbl2.text(objects.sl2.val());
    objects.lbl3.text(objects.sl3.val());//What if this select list is undefined for View1?
}
    })(jQuery);
```

To summarize, View #1 has SelectList1 & SelectList2. View #2 has all 3.  Is there a performance issue or is it bad practice to call a function where some of the variables are undefined?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a jQuery issue, not a JS one. jQuery simply does nothing (it does not even fail!) if you execute a method such as `.text()` or `.val()` on an empty result from a selector. For the performance issue, test it yourself. If the element is not found, I expect the performance to be a little better compared to when an element exists.

So, it's valid to use such code.

Note that you're mixing up "undefined variables" with "non-available elements" which are totally different matters. Using undefined variables is strongly discouraged and often lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: There are some really great answers here.  I would be interested to see if anyone had any additional comments based on my situation involving 'non-available-elements' and not 'undefined variables'.  I am actually using switch statements to check for values.  I was just curious. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's more about readability and maintainability at this point. I mean would it be clear to another developer just by looking at your JS that View #1 has SelectList1 & SelectList2 ? Looking at the code you would think it has all three since all the forms use the same JS. Maybe making it more flexible to where individual forms can specify which selectLists  are contained within the respective form, this way the global script is only using the selectLists specified in the forms and not assuming all at available.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is bad practice. And is source of bugs.

For good practice, define default value, and/or check for it in your function.

Answer (score 0):

thats why you should use the || operator

e.g. :

```
   ( $('#SelectList1').length || '0')
```

Comment: Not needed in that case, since `$('#SelectList1').length` will never be undefined or null.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you will introduce a level of uncertainty, and hence hard to trace bugs, if you do so. Different JS parsers will respond differently - some are more forgiving and will do nothing, others will just crash. So right away you have potential cross-browser issues.

Further, as those variables get passed around inside your code, if you do not know their values, you'll have a difficult time predicting how the rest of your code will interact with them. So now you also have potential logic/program bugs.

So do yourself a favor and a) check that any required parameters are passed, and do some error handling if it is not and b) make sure optional parameters are handled as soon as you receive them (eg assign them a default value, make sure they don't get passed on to other functions if they are not defined, whatever is most appropriate for your application logic).